# How to restrict other events from calling through a draggable event in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, events

I am actually stuck here. I am using the **drag** and **stop** event in jquery. Whenever I am dragging an element and when its **stop** event is fired, other events are also getting executed(event that are not called from the stop). I have used **event.stopPropagation()** to restrict other events from getting executed. But its really not working. Below is the code that I am using:

```
function RegisterServicesDraggableEvent(serviceElement) {
$(serviceElement).draggable({
    grid: [26, 0],
}, {
    drag: function (event, ui) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(this).find('.count-popup').css('display', 'none');
        $(this).find('.detail-popup').css('display', 'none');            
        $(this).parents('.timeline-bar').find('.add-new-service').hide();
        var parentLength1 = $(this).parents('.timeline-bar').find('.bar-steps').width();
        var parentLength2 = $(this).parents('.timeline-bar').find('.bar-steps').position().left;
        var parentLength3 = parentLength1 + parentLength2;
        var rightHighestValue = (parentLength3) - 28;
        var leftHighestValue = (parentLength2) + 7;
        if (ui.position.left < leftHighestValue) {
            ui.position.left = leftHighestValue;
        }
        if (ui.position.left > rightHighestValue) {
            ui.position.left = rightHighestValue;
        }
    },
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        event.stopPropagation();            
        ClosePopups();            

        //update popup for this priority
        SetServicesPopup($(this).parents('.timeline-bar'), priorityObj);                    
        $('.priority-timeline .timeline-list').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).parents('.timeline-list').addClass('selected');
        $(this).parents('.timeline-list').find('.priority-icon').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        //display the activity details    
        DisplayActivityDetail($(this), false);
        $(".service-timeline .activities").find('.edit-row.input-edit').each(function () {
            if ($(this).parents('.activities').hasClass('active'))
                $(this).parents('.activities').find('.sheduled-date').hide();
            else {
                $(this).parents('.activities').find('.sheduled-date').show();
            }
        });   


    }
});
```

}

Once the stop event is called, the following classes are added and css are applied. However as soon as the code finish executing, the control is passed to another event and it start executing, which returns negative results.

Any advice will be appreciated as I am really stuck in here..

Thanks,

Comment: `ClosePopups();` what is this doing there? actually you have called multiple functions inside is it i guess those are creating the issues.

Comment: Its a function that apply css

Comment: Jai but all the function does not trigger any of the event into which the control is getting transferred to

Comment: what are the other events that are executing ?